# Two select boxes for same model on form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I've got a form for a Group model

```
has_many :people, through: :group_persons   
has_many :group_persons
```

On the form, I want to have two select boxes where the user can select from the same list of People:

```
<%= f.label "Sub Group A" %>
<%= f.select :group_person_ids, Person.all %>

<%= f.label "Sub Group B" %>
<%= f.select :group_person_ids, Person.all %>
```

The selected people from each select box will BOTH get written into the group_persons table eventually, but I want them sent back to the controller as separate lists for handling first, so I want my parameters to look something like this:

> "group"=>{ 
>        "group_persons_subgroup_a"=>"1", "group_persons_subgroup_b"=>"3",
>        "commit"=>"Save"}

What do I need to do in the view to achieve this?

Comment: Sounds cool. Is there a question?

Comment: What do I need to do in the view to achieve this?

Comment: Have you considered giving them different names so they submit as different fields? You *may* have to use a `select_tag`, I'm not sure. Check it out.

Comment: Giving them different names would work, but I don't know syntax for doing that.... name is always generated from the method which is same for both. Not sure about the select_tag, I will look into that and see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [select_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag). It allows you to specify distinct names for your selects and, thereby, your submitted values.

It might look something like :

```
select_tag "group_persons_subgroup_a", options_from_collection_for_select(Person.all, "id", "name")
```

That may not be precisely correct, so you'll have to fiddle with it.

BTW, good on you for using `Person` instead of `User`. We are more than our role in relation to our computer!